# Pass multiple values using one argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to pass more than one value to an argument (the number of values I'm passing is different each time), but how can I do it? Here's my code:

```
usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-i <string>]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts ":i:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        i)
            i=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: use shift: here an example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174566/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shift-in-shell-scripts

Comment: consider updating the question with some command line examples of passing *more than one value* to your script; also provide an explanation of what the script is supposed to do with the multiple values (eg, store in an array? append to a variable? something else?)

Comment: #1 something liike this: `scripts.sh PARAM1=value1,value2,value3` ? or #2 `scripts.sh PARAM1=value1 PARAM1=value2 `

Answer (score 1):

I used this workaround with parsing values from the string
Use this as a delimter in a script

```
IFS=','
```

Then inside of an option when you assigning OPTARG to it:

```
OPTION_STRING=${OPTARG}
# Check if there is multiple values passed with IFS delimeter
read -ra my_array <<<$OPTION_STRING
```

Then for the logic check the lenght of array and if it's more than 1 do a cycle like this

```
if [ "${#my_array[@]}" -gt 1 ]; then
        # Do your something before the cycle
        # Cycling array for values
        for i in "${my_array[@]}"; do
            # Do what you need based on $i
        done
```

I guess it's too late for initial post, but maybe this may help someone else.